# How to copy whole Container from one Azure Blob Service to another with Azure Client Library v12

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying my hand at programmatic Azure tooling, specifically trying to copy/clone/move a Container from one Azure Blob Storage account to another one. I'm not seeing a good way to do this though with v12.x of the client library in its docs (so far at least).

For example:

```sh
BlobStorage1
|-- SomeContrainer
    |-- blob1
    |-- blob2
    |-- blob3

BlobStorage2
|-- SomeOtherContrainer
    |-- otherBlob
```

I want to programmatically move SomeContainer and all its blobs to BlobStorage2.

*What I've tried so far:*

docs read/consulated:

- [StartCopyFrom method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.specialized.blobbaseclient.startcopyfromuri?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_Specialized_BlobBaseClient_StartCopyFromUri_System_Uri_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobCopyFromUriOptions_System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

which doesn't seem to show how to go from account1 *pushed* to account2. You can pull down from account2 into account one but that's the opposite of what I'm after.

code attempt:

```cs
var localContainer = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(localContainerName);
var blobs = localContainer.GetBlobs();

var remoteClient = new BlobServiceClient(remoteConnectionString);
var remoteContainer = remoteClient.GetBlobContainerClient(localContainerName);

foreach(var blob in blobs)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"copying blob: {blob.Name}");
    var sourceBlob = localContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
    var remoteBlobClient = remoteContainer.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
    await remoteBlobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceBlob.Uri);
}
```

Problem here is that I could copy from remote to local (via connection string), or within the same account since the URI would be quite similar, but not from the account I'm on to a separate storage account. What would be the recommended way to copy blobs (or containers whole sale if possible) with the client library (v12.x) from one account to a separate one?

Comment: Why not use `azcopy`?

Comment: @GauravMantri Because I want the extra control you can get from the client library.

Comment: Understood. The code should not change whether you're copying blobs within same account or between two accounts. Are you getting any errors while executing the code above when copying between accounts?

Comment: Well the URI isn't correct as it's the blob I want to copy over. Could you provide an example of getting the correct URI in an answer? I would need to make a BlobClient for the remote blob (that doesn't yet exist) as well right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the code below:

```
    static async Task CopyContainersAcrossAccounts()
    {
        var sourceAccountName = "source-account";
        var sourceAccountKey = "source-account-key";
        var targetAccountName = "target-account";
        var targetAccountKey = "target-account-key";
        Azure.Storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential sourceCredential = new Azure.Storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(sourceAccountName, sourceAccountKey);
        Azure.Storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential targetCredential = new Azure.Storage.StorageSharedKeyCredential(targetAccountName, targetAccountKey);
        var sourceConnectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={sourceAccountName};AccountKey={sourceAccountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;";
        var sourceContainer = "source-container-name";
        var targetConnectionString = $"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={targetAccountName};AccountKey={targetAccountKey};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;";
        var targetContainer = "target-container-name";
        var sourceBlobContainerClient = new Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient(sourceConnectionString, sourceContainer);
        
        var targetBlobContainerClient = new Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobContainerClient(targetConnectionString, targetContainer);
        var sourceBlobs = sourceBlobContainerClient.GetBlobs();
        foreach (var blob in sourceBlobs)
        {
            //Get shared access signature with "Read" permission in case source container is a private container.
            Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasBuilder blobSasBuilder = new Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasBuilder()
            {
                BlobContainerName = sourceContainer,
                BlobName = blob.Name,
                ExpiresOn = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1)
            };
            blobSasBuilder.SetPermissions(Azure.Storage.Sas.BlobSasPermissions.Read);
            var sasToken = blobSasBuilder.ToSasQueryParameters(sourceCredential).ToString();
            var sourceBlobClient = sourceBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
            var targetBlobClient = targetBlobContainerClient.GetBlobClient(blob.Name);
            var sourceBlobUri = new Uri($"{sourceBlobClient.Uri.AbsoluteUri}?{sasToken}");
            await targetBlobClient.StartCopyFromUriAsync(sourceBlobUri);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `targetCredential` is never used. Is it normal?